# MSAccess Bug? Filter Seems To Be Affecting the Queries Underlying Left Join?

Tags: database, ms-access, join, database-design, left-join

I have a query that is simply taking a table and LEFT joining it to to other tables via 2 fields on 1 and 3 fields on the other table, there are no inner joins.

I'm encountering this weird behavior where the overall query seems to return blank for specific fields from one of the joined tables.  This behavior would be indicative usually of the query not finding any data to  join to the main table within the joined table.  The problem is that this data exists. What's even weirder is that if i do any filtering at all for the record that is blank whether via the access query drop downs or adding a WHERE clause to my query, the data now appears as it should have originally. It seems as though the act of me filtering is affecting whether or not the underlying join finds the value or not. From my understanding, this is not how left joins should operate? Any thoughts? Dropping the other table from the query seems to also fix the issue but why would that affect retrieving data via a left join? Relationship posted below for reference.

[image: Weird Join]

**EDIT** (Added Sql Query):

```sql
SELECT
  tbl_Supply1.CCT_Sales_Order AS Local_SO,
  tbl_Supply1.CLEANED_CCT_SERIAL_LOT AS Local_Serial,
  tbl_Supply1.Ship_Date AS Local_Date,
  tbl_Supply1.STATUS AS Local_Status,
  tbl_Supply1.PackingLeft,
  tbl_Supply1.PackingRight,
  dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data.sales_order AS Supply1_SO,
  dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data.item_sn AS Supply1_Serial,
  dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data.Date AS Supply1_Date,
  dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple.item_cd AS Master_Item,
  dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple.ser_lot_no AS Master_Serial,
  dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple.disposition AS Master_Disposition, 
  dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple.linked_ret_lbl AS Master_Return_Label 
FROM 
  (
    tbl_Supply1 LEFT JOIN dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data ON (
      tbl_Supply1.CLEANED_CCT_SERIAL_LOT = dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data.item_sn
    ) 
    AND (
      tbl_Supply1.Ship_Date = dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data.date
    )
    AND (
      tbl_Supply1.CCT_Sales_Order = dbo_cct_rfb_supplyone_data.sales_order
    )
  ) LEFT JOIN dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple ON (
    tbl_Supply1.PackingRight = dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple.ser_lot_no
  ) 
  AND (
    tbl_Supply1.PackingLeft = dbo_cct_rfb_master_status_simple.item_cd
  );
```

Comment: Please include the query code.

Comment: Kinda messy since I'm using alias', but here you go. Added to main post.

Comment: This may be impossible to answer without an [mcve], with sample data, and the results you get with & without filtering. Also maybe relevant: are you mixing local and ODBC tables here? What are the data types on the JOIN fields?

Comment: Can you show the names of the tables in the image above. Which table is named which?

Comment: @Andre The left Table is a local table and the two right ones are ODBC linked tables.  Is that known to occur? I'll edit in the table names in a sec.